# Pandas groupby with sum keeping a third column

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data set that looks like this:

```
Master  Sec     Amount
1234    98765   191
1234    98765   926
1234    98764   236
2345    76543   233
2345    76543   963
3456    54321   221
3456    54321   820
3456    43210   281
3456    32101   786
```

What I would like is to groupby the Master with a sum of the amount, but then apply that number to all of the uniques in the sec field, if that makes sense.

The results would look something like this:

```
Sec     Amount
98765   1353
98764   1353
76543   1196
54321   2108
43210   2108
32101   2108
```

I have code that already does this:

```
newdf= df[['Sec', 'Master']]
df = df[['Master', 'Amount']]
df = df.groupby(['Master'], as_index=False)['Amount'].sum()  
newdf = pd.merge(newdf, df, on='Master')
newdf = newdf[['Sec', 'Amount']]
newdf = newdf.drop_duplicates()
```

But creating a new dataframe doesn't seem particularly pythonic and I'm guessing that Pandas has a better way to do this.

Any advice?

Answer (score 2):

Here is one way. Since `groupby` returns a series, you can use this to map `Master`, and finally drop duplicate rows.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame([[1234, 98765, 191],
                   [1234, 98765, 926],
                   [1234, 98764, 236],
                   [2345, 76543, 233],
                   [2345, 76543, 963],
                   [3456, 54321, 221],
                   [3456, 54321, 820],
                   [3456, 43210, 281],
                   [3456, 32101, 786]],
                  columns=['Master', 'Sec', 'Amount'])

df['Amount'] = df['Master'].map(df.groupby('Master')['Amount'].sum())
df = df[['Sec', 'Amount']].drop_duplicates()

#      Sec  Amount
# 0  98765    1353
# 2  98764    1353
# 3  76543    1196
# 5  54321    2108
# 7  43210    2108
# 8  32101    2108
```

Answer (score 2):

Use [`GroupBy.transform`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.transform.html) for new column with [`DataFrame.drop_duplicates`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html) for remove duplicates by columns specifyning in `list`:

```
df['Amount'] = df.groupby('Master')['Amount'].transform('sum')
df = df.drop_duplicates(['Sec', 'Amount'])
print (df)
   Master    Sec  Amount
0    1234  98765    1353
2    1234  98764    1353
3    2345  76543    1196
5    3456  54321    2108
7    3456  43210    2108
8    3456  32101    2108
```